# Changing default Xcode Playground code

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I have been using playgrounds a lot while I work through a textbook, and every time I launch a new playground the default code appears:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

var str = "Hello, playground"
```

I am curious if there is any way to change the default code included when opening a new playground to something like this (for OS X):

```
import Cocoa
```

It is a small request, but having to delete the comment and Hello Playground lines of code in order to keep my playground nice and tidy gets tedious after a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*There's a way but it's a bit of a hack: modify the Playground template inside the Xcode app.*

Quit Xcode.

Select Xcode in the Applications folder then do "Show package contents".

Open `Contents` > `Developer` > `Library` > `Xcode` > `Templates` > `Source` > `Playground with Platform Choice.xctemplate` > `macOS`.

Select `___FILEBASENAME___.playground` then do "Show package contents".

Open the `Contents.swift` file in any text editor then modify/remove/add what you need (make a backup copy before changing the contents).

Save the file, then relaunch Xcode and make a new macOS playground: it will use your modified template.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is exactly what I was looking to do! I assumed it was going to be something like this method when I couldn't find any easily accessible options within xcode to change that type of thing.

I really appreciate your help, you have no idea how good it makes me feel to have a clean template when I open a new playground :D

Comment: @LanceNelson You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. :)